# Passing Data Between views with UIPageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a form that asks several questions, so I've split it into 3 view controllers where each view asks a subset of the total questions before saving it to my api. I am using `UIPageView` to allow a swipe between the 3 views.

How can I pass the answers from the questions from view controller 1 and 2 through to view controller 3.

I understand `UIpageViewControllerDataSource` is used to control what is rendered on each controller but how can I pass the data/answers between the controllers?
Is there maybe a better way of doing this ran using `UIPageView`?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is to pass data from a view controller to another, the best way to do so is with the `prepareForSegue` method.

For example if you want to pass a string from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`, give `ViewController2` a `NSString` property and in `ViewController1` implement the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ViewController2 *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.question = *yourvariablehere*;
}
```

I gave an example with a `NSString` but it could be any class you want.
Hope that helps.

Comment: perpareforSegue doesnt seem to be called on using UIPageView